# Radio Button never appears

Tags: c++, qt

With the following code to create radio buttons in a group box I get no results. A bit of background : in my display every objects has multiple variants and the user must choose which one to display (or all). What update/refresh command did I miss, or what is wrong ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_VARIANTS+1; i++)
    {
        m_variantButtons[i] = new QRadioButton();
        m_variantButtons[i]->setText(QString::number(i));
        m_variantButtons[i]->setObjectName(QString("m_pbDisplayVariant%1").arg(i));

        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(true);
        m_variantButtons[i]->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);

        ((QGridLayout*)(ui.m_groupBoxVariants->layout()))->addWidget(m_variantButtons[i], 1, i);
        ((QGridLayout*)(ui.m_groupBoxVariants->layout()))->update();
        connect(m_variantButtons[i], SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(updateDisplaySettings()));
        m_variantButtons[i]->setVisible(true);
    }
    ((QWidget*)(ui.m_groupBoxVariants))->updateGeometry();
```

Comment: I think, the right way is creating a vertical box layout, adding radio buttons to it and setting that layout to the group box. Why do you use grid layout? Do you set a layout to the group box?

Comment: I've reproduced your code and it actually worked. Where in your code   did you place this `for` loop?